# UISlider max/min image disappears (slider becomes transparent)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

A little confused about why this is happening. With both my iPhone 3GS & 4S (both running iOS 5), when I switch views and then return to the main view with the slider, the max/min images vanish but the slider's thumb remains. Here's what I've written to alter the slider style (in the `viewDidLoad` method):

```
[mySlider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMax.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mySlider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMin.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The slider (along with a label) is inside a `UIView` where I also have a function that fades the view in/out when a button is pressed, thus hiding/showing the label and slider. I'm not sure if that's relevant but here it is:

```
- (void)hideSlider {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [sliderView setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And `setAlpha:1.0` for the `showSlider` method. Filenames are correct (some images are located in separate groups, does this matter when referencing an image?)

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you move the first code snippet into `viewDidAppear:animated:` instead?

Comment: Still the same issue. I've tried removing it from the parent view when switching view controllers and adding it back but the problem still persists.

Comment: can you post entire view controller?  There's not enough info to decide what's happening.